# Uncertainty handling in the people stack

Tags: ros, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am interested to know how uncertainty about the positions and orientations of the people is handled in the people stack. I can already see a reliability filed in the positionMeasurement and person messages but I was wondering if there is already some documentation on this.
Also how can another people tracker which publishes the positions and orientations of the people can be integrated with this existing stack.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196696/uncertainty-handling-in-the-people-stack/) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [leg detector](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) uses a machine-learning approach to classify clumps of laser readings as leg or not, with a reliability estimate between 0 and 1.

A different detector could also publish the positionMeasurement message type.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0